# Magento error when trying to duplication product

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

I am using magento 1.7. i have got issue i don't know why this is happen. i just open product in backend for edit then click on duplicate then i got following error

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'new_file' in D:\wamp\www\easyshop\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Media.php on line 158
```

when i try following code to debug file:

```
print_r($newImages);
die;
```

then i got this following data

```
Array
(
    [/s/a/samsung_galaxy_s2_front1.jpg] => /s/a/samsung_galaxy_s2_front1_4.jpg
    [/s/g/sgs2p1.jpg] => /s/g/sgs2p1_4.jpg
    [/s/g/sgs2_11.jpg] => /s/g/sgs2_11_4.jpg
    [/s/g/sgs2-4386.jpg] => /s/g/sgs2-4386_4.jpg
)
```

I thing array keys are wrong can you please give solution to solve this problem

Comment: Maybe because you are running it on windows and Magento isn't supported on Windows?

Comment: I can confirm this happens on OS X too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem on 1.7.02. The solution I found was to change Magento's (IMHO) bugged code.

On Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media i've changed the lines where you find:

```
        // For duplicating we need copy original images.
        $duplicate = array();
        foreach ($value['images'] as &$image) {
            if (!isset($image['value_id'])) {
                continue;
            }
            $duplicate[$image['value_id']] = $this->_copyImage($image['file']);
            $newImages[$image['file']] = $duplicate[$image['value_id']];
        }
```

for:

```
        // For duplicating we need copy original images.
        $duplicate = array();
        foreach ($value['images'] as &$image) {
            if (!isset($image['value_id'])) {
                continue;
            }
            $duplicate[$image['value_id']] = $this->_copyImage($image['file']);
            $newImages[$image['file']] = array();
            $newImages[$image['file']]['new_file'] = $duplicate[$image['value_id']];
            $newImages[$image['file']]['label'] = $image['label'];
        }
```

It did the trick for me... Images are now being properly duplicated and enabled on new product.

Comment: You saved my butt thanks! Written it as an extension of the original class!! :)

Comment: this works for me: had no problems with magento 1.7.0.2 under php 5.3.15. error occured after upgrade to php 5.5.9. also php 5.4 patch for magento 1.7.0.2 didn't work.

Comment: Nice!  Thanks.  Can you file a bug on this at Magento?